# Change color of one segment

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I need to change the color of one edge (stroke) of a compound object in a map and can't use the scissors tool without losing the contents of the object. Is there any way to select one portion of a path without splitting it?

Answer (score 3):

Its possible to select it but not to color it (but that does not mean you can not overlay it with a separate segmet). Instead:

- Select the segment you want to color with direct selection tool (white arrow),
- copy it <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>,
- Paste it in front <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>,
- Clear fill and change stroke color.

Should do the trick